# Conjunction And to express one idea

Tags: grammar, expressions

Please take a look at this sentence:

> There is *a* philosophical question **and** *an* issue of humanity "what are aliens?".

In this one, I want to express "philosophical question"(a) and "issue of humanity"(b) as one idea-**a is b, and b is also a**. I researched and found an example:

> two singulars connected by 'and'become a plural, unless they present one idea as:
>
> The needle and the thread are on the table (2 things)
>
> The needle and thread is on the table (1 thing)

In my case, I don't know whether It's wrong or right to apply this example to my sentence.

> There is *a* philosophical question **and** *an* issue of humanity "what are aliens?".

Help me!

Comment: I'm not sure about the wisdom in close coordination here, but 'There is a philosophical question and [an] issue of humanity ...' is grammatical. But I'd put a colon and a capital to mark the 'quote' (and I'd use italics rather than quotes).

Comment: I agree with Edwin's comment, but I think you (Sour Tofu) are making a bad comparison.  "Needle and thread" is like "cup and saucer" or "knife and fork" — two distinct objects that can be considered as an aggregate.  I believe you're talking about two phrases that describe the same object, like "a gentleman and a scholar" (which refers to *one* person, not *two*).

Comment: Is **Help me!** supposed to be part of the last quote? If not, what's the difference between it and the first quote?

Comment: @Barmar No, that's my call for help.

Comment: @Scott yes, that's what I want to ask.

Comment: Well, I think my comment expressed my point of view: if you're talking about multiple aspects of one entity (as in "Edwin is a gentleman and a scholar"), you have a singular noun.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the singular form, because you're just describing one question.

A better way to express it, IMHO, would be:

> "What are aliens?" is both a philosophical question and an issue of humanity.